# how to access javascript constructor variables in nested prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am unable to access the constructor variable in RandObj.exampleFunction (this.name = "steven") in Example 1 due to the fact that the scoping of this in RandObj is limited to just the RandObj itself. This is because I have what I believe is a nested prototype going on, but I would like to keep this nested prototype since it is necessary for what I am trying to build out. I understand that I can access 'this.name' using example 2, but I would like to keep the structure that I have in example 1.

```
//EXAMPLE 1
define(function() {
    'use strict';

    var Wrapper = function(nameIn) {
        this.name = nameIn;
    };

    Wrapper.prototype = {
        RandObj: {
            exampleFunction: function() {
                this.name = "steven";
            }
        }
    };
    return Wrapper;
});


//EXAMPLE 2
define(function() {
    'use strict';

    var Wrapper = function(nameIn) {
        this.name = nameIn;
    };

    Wrapper.prototype = {
        exampleFunction: function() {
            this.name = "steven";
        }
    };
    return Wrapper;
});
```

Comment: `this` refers to the object it is a method of. Because you wrapped it in another object, it doesn't have reference to the parent object. Either move it to a direct method of `Wrapper` or declare `RandObj` in the constructor and set `this` to a variable for use in `exampleFunction`. If you haven't yet, you might want to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you can access the name is by first executing the function, then accessing the name.

```
Wrapper.prototype.RandObj.exampleFunction(); 
Wrapper.prototype.RandObj.name;
```

But I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve so I don't know if this is helpful.